# What is the difference between () => Int and Unit => Int? What on earth is the type of "()" in Scala?

Tags: scala

I think I still have not fully understood what type () represent during function definition. So I can't come up concrete example of each case: () => Int; Unit=> Int.

Can someone give me an easy example of function literal with type () => Int and type Unit=>Int respectively? After that, I think I can learn what () is exactly is.

Thanks

**EDIT: ** destin says they are same. But the following test seems to indicate otherwise: () can't be used in place expecting Unit.

```
scala> def inCase[A] ( b :Boolean, ifTrue : Unit => A, ifFalse : Unit => A ) : A  = 
 |     b match {
 |         case True => ifTrue()
 |         case _ => ifFalse()
 |     }

 inCase: [A](b: Boolean, ifTrue: Unit => A, ifFalse: Unit => A)A


scala> inCase( True,  () => 1,  () => -1 )
 <console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : () => Int
  required: Unit => ?
          inCase( True,  () => 1,  () => -1 )
```

Comment: Are you looking for a return type of int or Unit?  It sounds like it, but I want to make certain.

Comment: I am looking for a return type of Int.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`()` in a function type is not a type at all, nor is it a value. `() =>` is simply syntax to indicate a function that takes zero arguments. See the BNF notation in section 3.2.9 of [the Scala specification.](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)

When you see `(Type1, Type2, Type3) => Type4`, the `()` surrounds all of the argument types that the function takes. `(Type1, Type2, Type3)` is not a tuple type here -- the parentheses are just syntax. So when you see `() => Type4`, you have an argument list that takes zero parameters. Single argument functions are special, in that you can omit the parentheses.

Functions with no arguments, specified without the `()`, simply `=> Type4` are by-name parameters (which look like values, but are implemented as functions that get called implicitly when you try to evaluate their value.) They're defined in section 4.6.1 of the spec.

Parentheses can mean a bunch of other things in other contexts.

- Parentheses in a function type declaration anywhere other than right before the `=>` indicate a tuple type, and these can't be empty. (Section 3.2.5)
- Empty parentheses `()` are the return value of functions whose return type is `Unit`. (Section 12.2.3) This actually becomes a real value in certain contexts, for example `println(println("foo"))` will print

  ```
  foo                 <--- the argument to the inner println
  ()                  <--- the argument to the outer println
  ```
- Parentheses are also syntax for function arguments when you make a function call, something that you're probably already aware of. These can be empty. They're defined in section 6.6 of the spec.
- Parentheses are also syntax for function arguments when you define a method using `def`. These are described in section 4.6 of the spec.
- Parentheses are also the syntax for creating tuple values (Section 6.9). If they're not empty, you get a `TupleN` where `N` is the number of values inside of the parentheses. If they are empty, the type of this expression is `Unit`. (Sections 6.9, 12.2.3)

Comment: `{val f : Unit => Int = ((x:Unit)=>42) ; f(()) }` evaluates to 42. `{val g : () => Int = (()=>42) ; g() }` evaluates to 42. But curiously `{val h : Unit => Int = ((x:Unit)=>42) ; h() }` also compiles and evaluates to 42. I would have thought that, as I had passed h zero parameters instead of one, it would be a compile-time error.

Comment: And, interestingly, `{val k : Int => Int = ((a:Int) => 42) ; k()}` gives a "not enough arguments for method apply" rather than a type error. So there seems to be a special case for passing 0 arguments to a 1 argument function with domain of `Unit`.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your example, to have both notations (and to use the more popular Boolean):

```
def inCase[A] (b:Boolean, ifTrue: ()=> A, ifFalse: Unit => A): A = b match {
  case true => ifTrue ()
  case _    => ifFalse ()
}

inCase (true, () => 1,  (Unit) => -1)
```

Then I have to use the same notation on the calling site.

Answer (score -1):

`()` is the only instance of the type `Unit`. 

So `() => Int` as signature of a partial function means: takes *the* Unit object, does something and gives an Int.

`Unit => Int` means: takes *any* Unit object, does something and gives an Int.

**Edit**

*"Scala’s Unit type roughly corresponds to void in Java; it is used whenever a function does not return an interesting result. In fact, because Scala is an expressionoriented language, every function returns some result. If no explicit return expression is given, the value (), which is pronounced “unit”, is assumed. This value is
of type Unit. Unit-returning functions are also called procedures. Here’s a more
“expression-oriented” formulation of the swap function in the ﬁrst implementation
of quicksort, which makes this explicit:*

```
def swap(i: Int, j: Int): Unit = {
  val t = xs(i); xs(i) = xs(j); xs(j) = t
  ()
}
```

*The result value of this function is simply its last expression – a return keyword is
not necessary. Note that functions returning an explicit value always need an “=”
before their body or deﬁning expression."*

Source: Programming in Scala - Martin Odersky (Page 14)

Comment: No. `()=>Int` means a functions which takes no argument and returns an Int.

Comment: Your quote is correct, but is off-topic. In a *type signature for functions* `()` means no arguments which is mapped to Function0. If you define `val f:()=>Int = () => 12` and then you call it with a unit argument, it won't work: try `f()`and `f(())`.